# Bootstrap navbar icon and toggle button issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In the collapsible navbar, I have added a logo image but it is not responsive so I added a media query to shrink it but when I shrink the screen the toggle button moves down and the icon inside the toggle button not visible.

```css
.navbar{
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 0px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(175, 175, 175); 
}
.navbar-toggler{
 background-color: #2196f3;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.dropdown-item:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #2196f3!important;
}

/* media queries */
  @media (max-width:490px){
    .navbar-brand > img{
     width: 80%;
    }
    .navbar-brand{
     margin-right: 0px;
     /*text-align: center;*/
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/E1r683u.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must change width of `.navbar-dark .navbar-brand`in @media

```
@media (max-width:...px){
    .navbar-dark .navbar-brand{
       width: ...; 
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar{
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 0px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(175, 175, 175); 
}
.navbar-toggler{
 background-color: #2196f3;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.dropdown-item:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #2196f3!important;
}

.navbar-toggler{
  color:#2196f3 !important;
  border-color:#2196f3 !important;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(33,150,243, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
.nav-link{
  color:#2196f3 !important;
}
.nav-link:hover{
  color:#8ac6f6 !important;
}
/* media queries */
  @media (max-width:890px){
    .navbar-brand{
       width: 50%; 
    }
    .navbar-brand{
     margin-right: 0px;
     /*text-align: center;*/
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/E1r683u.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

Comment: reducing the width resolves the problem but the icon bar is not visible if I change the navbar background-color to white and removing the bg-dark class. So now the background is white but the toggle button is not visible so I changed the color to #2196f3 now button is visible but no inside bars (those three dashes ) are not showing

Comment: @TakshakRajput for change color of inside bars (those three dashes ) must change the value of *stroke* in the background-image of *.navbar-toggler-icon*

Answer (score 1):

Bootsrap provide us the efficient way for this i.e., row and column feature.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="row"><div class="col-8">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/E1r683u.png" class="img-fluid"></a></div>  <div class="col-4">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">        
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the bootstrap `.container` class having a `flex-wrap` value of `wrap`. adding this:

```
.container{
  flex-wrap:nowrap !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ukynjx3L/1/

Comment: If I add this property, the problem resolves but the menu items start from the top on tap and not from the below nav bar